# How to create a coustem react native template

Tags: javascript, react-native, yarnpkg, react-templates

I want to create a custom react native template I am using this [link](https://dev.to/roycechua/how-to-make-your-own-custom-react-native-templates-2021-20l5) as a reference I have created a template and pushed the code to git but when I try to create a react native app with the template I am getting the error [image: Tempalte downalod error]

Comment: This appears to be a yarn configuration / setup / whatever issue, rather than a Git one (though it manifests as a Git hint and error). I'm not sure [tag:yarnpkg] is the right tag, but it's certainly no worse than [tag:git].

Comment: Actually, it works with a sample template `https://github.com/Esemesek/react-native-new-template`.